# Unity3d Undo is a EditorWindow [for bools and strings]

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Here is my code,

```
 CoreGlobal.OnMobile = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Mobile Build", CoreGlobal.OnMobile);

         if (Selection.activeGameObject && Selection.activeGameObject.tag == "CBC")
         {
             selectedTransform = Selection.activeGameObject.transform;
             fold = EditorGUILayout.InspectorTitlebar(fold, selectedTransform);
             if (fold)
             {
                 selectedTransform.position =
                     EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field("Position", selectedTransform.position);
                 EditorGUILayout.Space();
                 rotationComponents =
                     EditorGUILayout.Vector4Field("Detailed Rotation", QuaternionToVector4(selectedTransform.localRotation));
                 EditorGUILayout.Space();
                 selectedTransform.localScale =
                     EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field("Scale", selectedTransform.localScale);
             }
             selectedTransform.localRotation = ConvertToQuaternion(rotationComponents);
             EditorGUILayout.Space();
         }
```

this is the code I have in my editor window, onGUI function.

I am trying to create a undo for the code. I am not sure how to undo the Toogle Value.
`Undo.RecordObject(OBJECT, STRING);`

What are the ways that I could change the bool to Object so I could undo it ? if anyone could get me started just for the bool, i could do the rest.

Comment: `Undo.RecordObject(Selection.activeTransform, "Set bar");` Works when changing transform in my custom editor. But other than that :/

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is a perfect answer, but you could do something with this callback.  Its not a perfect solution but it should be a start.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo-undoRedoPerformed.html

And then you could register an undo with a dummy Object, and then somehow figure out how to detect what kind of undo was done?